# Error with logical binary infix operator

Tags: ios, swift, operators

I want to add custom operator `&=` like in Objective-C:

```
precedencegroup HighPrecedence {
    assignment: true
    associativity: left
    higherThan: BitwiseShiftPrecedence
}

infix operator &= : HighPrecedence
func &=(lhs: Bool, rhs: @autoclosure () -> Bool) -> Bool {
    return lhs && rhs()
}

var i = true
i &= 1 > 0
```

But I have an error  in last line:

> error: left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: 'i' is immutable
>   i &= 1 > 0

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `&=` operator *mutates* the left operand, therefore you have
to define `lhs` as an *inout parameter* (instead of returning
a value).

You can also remove your operator definition, `&=` is already defined
in the Swift standard library as

```
infix operator &= : AssignmentPrecedence
```

(used for `BitwiseOperations`). So this is sufficient and works as expected:

```
func &=(lhs: inout Bool, rhs: @autoclosure () -> Bool) {
    lhs = lhs && rhs()
}

var i = true
i &= 1 < 0
```

Comment: How I can change priority of my operator to remove parentheses in `i &= (1 < 0)` expression?

Comment: @ArtemNovichkov: Just choose `AssignmentPrecedence`.